# When to use NEWID or NEWSEQUENTIALID and why

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

I am trying to understand the practical real-life usage of `NewId` and '`NewSequentialId`, I usually use the `Identity` property when creating new table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    [ID]    INT             PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [NAME]  NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Is the above code not the best practice, If so should I replace it with this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    [ID]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    [NAME]  VARCHAR(MAX)    NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Or with this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    [ID]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [NAME]  nVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL
);
GO
```

**Question: Is NewId or NEWSEQUENTIALID a replacement for Identity, if not when to use each one?**

I am not trying to use the `NewId` or `NewSequentialId` as `Primary Key`, the code above is for demonstration purpose only, and maybe this code is better like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    [ID]        INT                 NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [ROWGUID]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    [NAME]      nVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Comment: FIrst `INSERT INTO MYTABLE ( NAME ) VALUES ('Ashraf Abusada');` and then `INSERT INTO MYTABLE ( NAME ) VALUES ('Ashraf Abusada');` -- didn't we just create a duplicate? Yes, stop using `IDENTITY` and don't use `NEWID()` or `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` for the same reason.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use code generated sequence instead?

Comment: I'm suggesting a table with a key only on the `IDENTITY` column has no real data integrity and that you should rethink your entire approach rather than investigate other sequence numbers.

Comment: @onedaywhen ,what example you have taken to prove your point is wrong ?Name can be duplicate.It is not efficient to make varchar column PK.Suppose even if any varchar column like email are unique in any table then we don't make email PK.we take identity column as PK and check the duplicate conbstraint via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary use of GUIDs as primary keys is in distributed systems, where you want unique IDs among clients without the overhead of a roundtrip to the server/database.

They can come with their own problems, such as fragmentation if used as a clustering key (which can be mitigated with appropriate periodic index rebuilds).

I would not use [`SEQUENTIALID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017); instead use a 'Comb' GUID if you want ordering.

[The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Keys](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between `newsequentialid()` and COMB GUIDs? Or provide a link to something explaining the differences?

Comment: The article referenced is far out of date and although some of it still applies it's missing important information. From looking at it the so called COMB guid is pretty similar to what newsequentialid() does and thus the performance gains touted by the author are not really applicable. His comparison only accounts for newid() and not the newer newsequentialid().

Comment: this doesn't answer the question which asks for differences between newid() and newsequentialid() - actually it doesn't take differences into account at all.

Comment: @eis: sometimes you have to answer the real question....

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it right, a GUID is not always good in performance because it is not a sortable field for an index.
The sequentialid can overcome this problem by creating GUID's that are much better sortable and thus makes better index for your table.

I know it is a bit more complicated than this, but I am trying to explain as simple as possible.

So if you want to use GUID as primary keys, then I suggest using the sequentialID.

You should ask yourself why you want a GUID as primary key; if not needed, then don't.

Comment: Guids are sortable. But due to their random nature a new record can be stuck anywhere in the index leading to index fragmentation

Answer (score 0):

GUID keys are unique worldwide. They should be used if you wish to have your keys are unique worldwide. For example multiple servers in clusters, or work with maps in cartography.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the OP's full question.

Comment: It also incorrect.  NEWID() in SQL Server uses Type 4 GUIDs, which are nothing more than large random numbers with a huge domain of values (2^122 {6 bits are reserved for GUID Type and Version identification) but they are NOT guaranteed to be unique.  Collisions are possible even between just 2 machines).